# Spring MVC: The request sent by the client is syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have some problems when trying to use `@SessionAttribute` in Spring MVC Controller. I have already saved the session but when I show the session to the view again, it gives an error:

> HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request :The request sent by the client is
> syntactically incorrect.

but when i remove `@SessionAttribute` it works normally

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login/")
public class LoginController {
    
    @GetMapping
    public String Default(@SessionAttribute("email") String email) {
        System.out.println(""+email);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that there is no such attribute in the session.  Try using @SessionAttributes annotation on the method and pause it in the debugger.  You'll have a chance to look at the session attributes and see that there isn't one named "email"

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting "HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request" is that your email attribute saving logic into the session might not be working and that's why there is no `email` attribute present in the session.

As a result, this annotation `@SessionAttribute("email")` is giving you a Bad Request error because no attribute named `email` is found in the session.

Set the required attribute to false like this `@SessionAttribute(name = "email", required = false)` and your issue will be fixed. Now if there is any attribute in the session named `email` it will be picked up by spring and will be injected into the method otherwise, the email parameter will be a null value and spring won't throw any Bad Request error.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttribute.html) for `@SessionAttribute` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because there is no attribute named email found in the session. You can try to modify the controller class as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login/")
public class LoginController {

  @GetMapping
  public String Default(@SessionAttribute(name="email",required=false) String email) {
      System.out.println(""+email);
      return "login";
  }
}
```

This will ensure that even if the session doesn't contains the 'email' attribute, it won't cause your application to fail as spring will set a null value by default. And you can add a null check explicitly in the method to handle this scenario.